# Filtrar duas linhas do arquivo ao mesmo tempo mostrar apenas a segunda?

Tags: regex, while, sed, awk, grep

Tenho o seguinte arquivo fictício:

```
Location: Estado
Title: Bahia

Location: Estado
Title: Pernanbuco

Location: Estado
Title: Alagoas

Location: Cidade
Title: Recife

Location: Cidade
Title: Barretos

Location: Estado
Title: Roraima

Location: Estado
Title: Tocatins
```

Preciso filtrar as duas linhas ao mesmo tempo, e retonar apenas a segunda referente a primeira 'Location: [...]'

Tentei alguns comandos, porém, vou postar aqui somente um! Acredito ser o mais limpo para entendimento de quem lê.

```
cat info.txt | grep Cidade | awk 'NF' | awk '/Title:/{print $1}'
```

> Neste comando acima, estou buscando os títulos da(s) localização que são as 'cidades'. Note que no arquivo só há duas cidades, e deveria me retorna o 'Title: [...]' dessas respectivas cidades.

A saída deveria ser, mas não estou conseguindo.. essa daqui:

```
Cidade

Recife
Barretos
```

Essa é toda lógia, espero que tenha entendido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para este formato de arquivo, uma opção seria:

```
grep Cidade -A 1 info.txt | grep Title | awk -F: '{gsub(" +","");print $2}'
```

O primeiro `grep` pega as linhas que têm "Cidade", e a opção `-A 1` também pega uma linha depois destas. Ou seja, este `grep` resulta no seguinte:

```
$ grep Cidade -A 1 info.txt 
Location: Cidade
Title: Recife
--
Location: Cidade
Title: Barretos
```

Depois eu faço outro `grep` pegando somente as linhas com "Title", e por fim o `awk` separa a linha por `:`, o `gsub` elimina o espaço que tem logo em seguida e no final imprimo o nome da cidade. A saída será:

```
Recife
Barretos
```

Comment: Grato pela resposta bem explicada. O fator primordial era tão somente o parâmetro `-A 1` do comando `grep` que nesse caso eu precisava saber. Então, substitui o segundo `grep Title` da sua resposta pelo `awk -F "Title:" '{print $2}'`. Agora, ficou assim: `cat info.txt | grep Cidade -A 1 | awk -F "Title:" '{print $2}'`, somente para ficar amigável para mim lembrar.